# Unable to Run Celery and celery beat using docker in django application (Unable to load celery application)

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery, django-celery-beat

when I am trying to run my application I using without docker its working perfectly , but In docker-compose I am getting this error :

```
               | Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
               | Unable to load celery application.
               | The module sampleproject was not found.
```

my **docker-compose** file

```
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    hostname: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sampleproject
    tty: true
    command: >
      bash -c "
        python manage.py migrate &&
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      "
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine

  celery:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery  -A sampleproject worker -l info
    depends_on:
     - database
     - redis

  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A sampleproject beat -l info
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
      - celery
```

my **Docker file**

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir \
  && rm -rf requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /project
WORKDIR /project
```

my folder structure is something like this :

[image]

Comment: from your `Dockerfile` it seems like you don't add your app source code (unless it's installed as a package in your `requirements.txt` which I cannot see here

Comment: @ItayB  which app sir ? are you talking about docker-compose `app` ?

Comment: `app = Celery('my_app', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')`

Comment: where I am suppose to put this ? I have this in `celery.py`  as    
   `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sampleproject.settings")
app = Celery("sampleproject") `  @ItayB

Comment: Try to inspect the `celery` container that is running after compose is up to check if there is actually a `sampleproject` folder. Make sure the context on which the celery command is executed, it's the expected one, sampleproject should be a sub-folder.

Comment: @NicoE I dont know how I can inspect into celery container . is there any specific command ?

Comment: I meant something like `docker-compose exec celery bash`, being *celery* the name of the service declared on your compose file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and with that we found the solution. In fact, celery is right to complain about not being able to run, as it needs an instance of the application.

For that, it is only necessary to add the volume directive in the docker-compose .yaml file, directing to the project folder, in case into the service celery and celery-beat.

**Example:**

```
   app:
    container_name: myapp
    hostname: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sampleproject
    tty: true
    command: >
      bash -c "
        python manage.py migrate &&
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      "
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine

  celery:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery  -A sampleproject worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    depends_on:
     - database
     - redis

  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A sampleproject beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
      - celery
```

So when the celery container is executed it will see that there is a volume and will execute the project without any problems.